# Extjs4 Accordion - inline link to go between panels

Tags: extjs, accordion

I have a basic ExtJS 4.0 accordion. I want to have an inline  link within the text of one panel that will close that panel and open another.

In the example below, the link in Panel 1 should open Panel 2. What sort of click function would work here?

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
title: 'Accordion Layout',
layout:'accordion',
layoutConfig: {
    // layout-specific configs go here
    titleCollapse: false,
    animate: true,
    activeOnTop: true
},
height: 300,
width: 400,
items: [{
    title: 'Panel 1',
    id: 'p1',
    html: 'Text goes here. <p><a id="linkP2" href="#">Go to panel 2</a></p>'
},{
    title: 'Panel 2',
    id: 'p2',
    html: 'Panel content!'
},{
    title: 'Panel 3',
    id: 'p3',
    html: 'Panel content!'
}],
renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up finding a rather simple solution:

```
<a id="linkP2" href="javascript:onClick=Ext.getCmp(\'p2\').expand();">Go to panel 2</a>
```

Ext.getCmp.expand allows the selection of a certain ID within the accordion.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one that I did recently to change the expanded panel for a tab key navigation handler. My accordion panel was contained in a tabpanel so the first variable gets the active tab, you could change that however you want to get accordion panel itself as fits your needs, something like:

```
var tab = Ext.ComponentQuery.select(panel[layout=accordion]);
```

would work for you to get a reference to the accordion if this is the only accordion panel in your app.

```
// direction arg is either 1 or -1 depending on whether we want to go
// forward or backward
shiftPanels: function(direction) {
    var tab = this.getMainPanel().getActiveTab(), // gets the active tab panel
        panels = tab.items, // gets all of the accordion panels
        active = tab.child('[collapsed=false]'), // gets the expanded panel
        shifted;

    // get the panel at direction + index (the panel we want to expand)
    panels.each(function(panel, idx) {
        if (active == panel) {
            shifted = panels.getAt(direction + idx);
            return false;
        }
    });

    // expand the shifted panel or wrap around to the beginning or end
    if (shifted) {
        shifted.expand();
    } else if (direction > 0) {
        shifted = panels.getAt(0);
        shifted.expand();
    } else {
        shifted = panels.getAt(panels.length - 1);
        shifted.expand();
    }
},
```

Comment: This helped, but I ended up finding a rather simple solution. This is a nice way when enable use of keyboard tabbing.